# Connect to Remote Oracle Database Using tnsnames.ora in shared directory in c#

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am developing a C# program that connects to an Oracle database located in an intranet computer. A tnsnames.ora file is located in a shared directory and have several connection options. How do I use this tnsnames.ora file to connect to the database.

The contents of the tnsnames.ora file may change and would be updated in the shared directory. Copying just the required connection string and using in within the code is not an option.

Users should be able to select desired connection option from the tnsnames.ora

Comment: On the startup of the app can you read the tnsnames.ora and stock the result (in a file or in static data) ?

Comment: You´ll need an oracle client for this. No need to read tnsnames.ora yourself.

Comment: You may consider to configure a Oracle Naming server, see [Fusion Middleware Administrator's Guide for Oracle Internet Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e10029/toc.htm) instead of a shared `tnsnames.ora` file.

Comment: Tnsnames file is stored locally and is maintained by yourself, so it's irrelevant. You can connect directly to the Oracle instance, using the host:post:sid combination instead.

Answer (score 0):

The tnsnames.ora file is a configuration file that contains network service names mapped to connect descriptors for the local naming method, or net service names mapped to listener protocol addresses.

For more detail.
[enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF259)

Comment: Saleem, thank you for the answer. The tnsnames.ora do contain the connection details but I cannot find any example of how to read this tnsnames and extract relevant information to connect rather than copying the connection details directly to the program.